# Как правильно передать массив данных в POST запросе?

Tags: php

У Яндекса нашел образец POST запроса, а отправить его не могу, получаю bool(false)

Вот, что предлагает Яндекс:

**Тело запроса**

```
{
  "board_id": string,
  "content": [
    {
      "source": {
        "url": string
      },
      "source_type": string
    }
  ],
  "description": string,
  "source_meta": {
    "page_domain": string,
    "page_title": string,
    "page_url": string
  }
}
```

Отправить пытаюсь так:

```
$body = '{
  "board_id": 3e5005e000000000092c234,
  "content": [
    {
      "source": {
        "url": https://site.ru/123934.jpg
      },
      "source_type": image
    }
  ],
  "description": Описание карточки. Максимальная длина описания — 2048 символов.,
  "source_meta": {
    "page_domain": site.ru,
    "page_title": Заголовок страницы с контентом,
    "page_url": https://site.ru
  }
}';

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'  => 'POST',
    'header'  => "Host: api.collections.yandex.net\r\n".
    "Authorization: OAuth AgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADDDDDDDD3jHzZ8\r\n".
    "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8\r\n".
    "Accept: application/json\r\n",
    'content' => $body
  )
);
                   
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
$url = 'https://api.collections.yandex.net/v1/cards/?as_company=my_company';
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

[Документация](https://yandex.ru/dev/collections/doc/ref/Cards/cards_post-docpage/)

Где я ошибся?
Как верно отправить запрос?

Спасибо!

Comment: $body - записываете массив и делаете json_encode, а не просто строку вписываете. собираете все нужные данные и делаете запрос через curl (примеры:[ya disk](https://snipp.ru/php/disk-yandex), [php curl](https://snipp.ru/php/curl), [ya curl авторизация](https://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=1666))

Comment: Не могу корректно $body в массив записать, пробовал explode и json_encode https://i.gyazo.com/259f01e4e8e6643a93a9f82184a12da9.png , получил bool(false), делал не через cURL. Массив не верный скорее всего получается из моего $body

Comment: [php array to json](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e8d75702283ce67edae7505969002439704ddece)

Comment: Большое спасибо!